# Ransack - dropdown without duplicates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

I created the following form with Ransack to filter out products.

```
<%= f.select :shop_id_cont, options_from_collection_for_select(Product.all, "shop_id", "shop_id", @search.shop_id_cont), include_blank: true %>
```

This creates the dropdown but for each product the shop_id repeats. How can I change the form to get only each shop_id once?

Comment: This seems correct to me. If you open a Rails console (in the same environment that you notice the problem) and do `Product.all.map(&:shop_id)` what will be the output?

Comment: Output has the same issue - values are duplicated for each product.. hmm

Comment: That might mean that the problem is in your data, not the code posted?

Comment: The data contains a list of products, each one with a different shop_id. I want the code to show the shop_id but only once.